# Automatically mark as read for specific folder in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there any way that I can mark emails "as read" automatically. I have some folders that are receiving automatic reports. I don't need to read them, I just need to have them if needed in emails. So emails will be read as soon as they are in or it could be a specific delay, e.g 5 mins. Is this possible in Outlook 2016? So I don't need to click on them. This should apply for specific folders not for entire mail box.

Thanks xD.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a mail rule that moves the messages you are referring to in to a separate folder automatically when they arrive.

Add to that rule the action called: `mark it as read`

If you don't already have a rule, then you can create one to identify the mail in question and `mark it as read` among other things.

[image]

Comment: Thanks xD. Is there any way to make them read in lets say 5 mins?

Comment: This makes it a client-only rule, which isn't really useful for keeping things in sync between machines.

Comment: @KrisHarper If you add this rule to all your machines then it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Appleoddity not all clients execute rules. E.g. mobile clients or Outlook web access.

Answer (score 0):

@Appleoddity, what about the scenarios when the mail rules are server-side and it is just needed a folder rule to mark the messages as read, in that certain folder? Mark as read is a client-side rule so cannot be applied server-side